# How to set SVG as default rendering in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg, r-markdown

When using JupyterLab, there is a command `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'` that displays plots as `svg`. The quality is awesome. I would like to ask if there is a similar command for Rnotebook, i.e.

- Display plots inside Rnotebook as `svg`.
- Display plots in the output html as `svg`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For every code chunk that you want to produce svg output, you simply set the `dev = 'svg'` chunk option. Or you can set this option globally with `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = 'svg')` at the beginning of your markdown document.

Save the following as a `.Rmd` file, knit, and see what you get.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = 'svg') # set output device to svg
```

A simple plot, as svg file:

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, color = hp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_viridis_c()
```
````